Derivative computation of a function $f\in C^{\infty}(GL_2(\mathbb{R}))$
Let
$$g=\begin{bmatrix}
    u&\\&u
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    \sqrt{y}&x\sqrt{y}\\
    &1/\sqrt{y}
\end{bmatrix}k_\theta,\quad k_\theta=\begin{bmatrix}
        \cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
        -\sin\theta&\cos\theta
    \end{bmatrix},\qquad W=\begin{bmatrix}
        0&1\\-1&0
    \end{bmatrix}$$
Then I understand that $\exp(tW)$ is just $k_t$ and that
$$g\exp(tW)=\begin{bmatrix}
    u&\\&u
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    \sqrt{y}&x\sqrt{y}\\
    &1/\sqrt{y}
\end{bmatrix}k_{\theta+t}$$
Now I don't understand the following equality
$$(dWf)(g)=\frac{d}{dt}f(g\exp(tW))|_{t=0}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f(g),$$
where the first equality is just the definition. Where does the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$ come from?
